# Assembly infinite sized number

Tags: assembly, binary, numbers, embedded, bigint

I think this question may be a bit dumb..

Since we store bits to indicate a number, and since we have a whole RAM, we should be able to have a infinity-sized (actually, custom-sized) number that could take up to the whole RAM (or a specified part of it).

Correct?

So if we were to do for example:

```
mov ax, 0xFFFF
add ax, 1
jc custom_function ; if I remember correctly jc checks the carry flag
```

And custom_function is a label/function that has an algorithm to set the next bits to create an infinite-sized number.

**Questions**

1. Would that be possible?
   If not infinite-sized numbers, a custom specified (that's longer or shorter than the defaults)
2. I suspect that, if it IS possible, it will have bad performance (even if the number if shorter). What do you think?
3. Do you think it would be good to have something like this?
   (Maybe that would be more effective in older systems or embedded systems were ram is limited?)

Comment: Sure, this sort of thing is both possible and done frequently in practice.  Check out big number libraries like GMP for this sort of thing.

Comment: "infinite-sized number" is not a phrase that anybody with a passing understanding of mathematics is going to be happy with.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yeah, I guess you're right.. I should have said, different-sized numbers and types

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: A good term for what they're trying to describe is "arbitrary precision", like Python integers, which never overflow.  They just keep growing, allocating more space to store more bits (in 4-byte chunks.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Comment: Can all be done, and is done, but there is no need to do it yourself, and doing in assembly language would be an heroic waste of life.  With respect to performance, values in machine words can be loaded and stored efficiently and fundamental operations are single instructions.  Arbitrary precision numbers require more instructions to load and save data and to operate on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Would that be possible? If not infinite-sized numbers, a custom specified (that's longer or shorter than the defaults)

Yes, of course. You can define any representation and data type you want, only limited by the environment.

However, since the size of your memory is finite, the range of values is also finite. Even if you feel that gigabytes are "kind of" infinite. Just think about calculating the math constant PI with even more digits. At some point your RAM is full.

The standard term is [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), or bignum / bigint.  One way to handle it is a dynamic array of words (like C++ `std::vector`), with an upper limit imposed by practical limits of the system, but only using as much storage as the number actually needs.

> 2. I suspect that, if it IS possible, it will have bad performance (even if the number if shorter). What do you think?

It depends. If you implement some clever algorithm on an 8 bit machine, the performance with 6 bit values of such a special type is probably better than the performance with `long`.

But for sure, at the latest when the special type has more bits than the longest supported "standard" type, the performance will degrade.  If you store your bignums as dynamic arrays, you always have an extra level of indirection which adds overhead even for small numbers.

Small-number optimizations are possible, like a flag bit to treat the bits as a value, not a pointer.  (Python implementations do something like this; Python 3 integers are always arbitrary precision, so the normal case is small integers that fit in one "chunk" of bits.)  This still takes more code to check stuff, compared to just a simple `add` instruction.

> 3. Do you think it would be good to have something like this? (Maybe that would be more effective in older systems or embedded systems were ram is limited?)

There are already libraries providing such types, for example [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), the GNU Multiprecision Library, which has hand-written asm for most architectures (including 32 and 64-bit x86).

In "the olde days" such an algorithm was standard even on PCs. For example, I started my career around 1980 with the Intel 8080 and the Z80 processors, where you commonly use 8 bit arithmetic. They *had* 16 bit addition and subtraction instructions, but their usage involved a lot of moving values in and out registers.

The instruction sets include addition instruction with and without taking a carry into account. And the same for subtraction. With these instructions, even these ancient processors can handle deliberately wide values.

Oh, 8 bit machines are still in use today. Look up Arduino with AVR, for example. But these are for a special hobby niche. There are probably more 16 bit (and less) processors in use in the world than PCs, commonly hidden as "embedded" controllers.

Comment: I made some edits to add some more implementation details, e.g. about handling the array of limbs like `std::vector` as a way for it to be variable length, only using about as much storage as needed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, thanks, it is a valuable extension! (I did not go into such details, under the impression that the OP thinks in assembly language, as the code snippet suggests.)

Comment: Well sure, but `std::vector` is a convenient way to summarize the assembly-language implementation of something like that.  A start+end pointer, optionally with an end-of-allocation pointer if you want to grow in-place without realloc.  C++ is low enough level that you can ahead-of-time compile it and look at the asm, but high enough level that it has dynamic containers.